# Can I use publish an application using SDL, even commercially?

Tags: application-development, license

I wrote a game in Windows a while back, and I'd like to port it to finish it under Ubuntu, especially as I could publish it via the software centre. However, It's written in C/++ and OpenGL, with SDL for windowing & input.

The SDL site says:

> "SDL is distributed under GNU LGPL version 2. This license allows you
>   to use SDL freely in commercial programs as long as you link with the
>   dynamic library."

And after reading around, I've heard there are a few restrictions I need to take into account with the LPGPL V2 license. Personally, I've honestly tried and I simply can't get my head around all these licenses.

Can anyone here tell me whether I can use it commercially or do I need to cut out all the SDL framework?

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you get a response here telling you 'yeah, it's fine' and you get sued then what? Some legal questions are okay here but I think most are not. Good luck with the game anyway.

Comment: @TomBrossman This is a simple question about the LGPL. Maybe it's off-topic for being insufficiently about Ubuntu, but I think this is far more objectively answerable by non-experts than most licensing questions we consider on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use SDL in a commercial project. The LGPL allows you to link SDL to proprietary code. (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGPL#Differences_from_the_GPL), [this article](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-not-lgpl.html), and [that version](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.0.html) of [the license itself](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/old-licenses.html#LGPL).) What it means is if you change *SDL* you have to also release *those* changes under the LGPL.

It is, of course, important that you *read and understand the license itself before creating any derivative work of a work licensed with it*, including before creating a program (proprietary or otherwise) that links to SDL.

Furthermore, please note that this answer is provided for general informational purposes only.
***This post is not legal advice.***

Comment: A good case study: [Dungeons of Dredomor](http://www.dungeonsofdredmor.com/).  Gaslamp Games legally used SDL to create DoD, and now they have a good, cross-platorm game which has appeared in a Humble Indie Bundle, and, speaking as a owner of it, is pretty solid and well-made.